# Conditional skip of code lines

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, tuples

I have a `time_slots` list of sublists, which looks like this:

```
[[(37913.0, 0.3104248046875),
(37917.0, 0.3106689453125),
(37919.0, 0.31201171875)],
[(37945.0, 0.3123779296875), (37947.0, 0.31201171875)],
[],
[(37977.0, 0.311279296875),
(37979.0, 0.310791015625),
(37981.0, 0.3106689453125)],
[(38008.0, 0.31103515625),
(38011.0, 0.31005859375),
(38012.0, 0.3109130859375)],
[],
[(38039.0, 0.3095703125),
(38042.0, 0.3101806640625),
(38044.0, 0.3123779296875)],
[],
[],
```

I am applying a `for` loop on `time_slots` array which is like:

```
for y in range(0,len(time_slots)):

    x_points,y_points = zip(*time_slots[y])
    inrplt_func = interpolate.CubicSpline(x_points,y_points)
```

Notice that there are empty lists in `time_slots` (e.g 3rd and 6th elements). **What i want to do is tuple unpacking line if list is empty**
I know i can use `break` but i don't want leave loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `continue` if you want to skip the empty lists.

```
for y in range(0,len(time_slots)):
    if len(buckets[y]) == 0:
       continue
    x_points,y_points = zip(*buckets[y])
    inrplt_func = interpolate.CubicSpline(x_points,y_points)
```

`continue` lets you skip the current iteration and start the next iteration.